# Using search core results to display google like search page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search

I have the custom list with the two columns in newsletter style but what about adding in a search web part onto a separate page, how can i get that to search my faq custom list?

For example a user can input a question into the search web part on the search page and that question will return the results most relevant to their search from the Q and A list; kind of like a google search

Answer (score 1):

Add `site:urlOfList` as AdditionalQuery to the Search Core Results web part

Here is where you add this in the UI:
[image]

Comment: Where can i add that code, through sharepoint designer?

Comment: You can add that in the browser see above

Comment: final question: so I would like the interface to look similar to google just with my company logo etc, i would like it to work the same way.

Can i setup a separate sharepoint page that has a search boxz web part on it and use that to search through my custom list?

Comment: Yes you just add a new page and the add the web parts you need 'search box', 'search core results', paging, ...

Comment: interesting, how does the user enter in search terms to search a list? they will not be able to see the list of course the results returned would be from the list.

Comment: The user just enters the text to search for in the search box. The `site:urlOfList` added in the result web part limits the search to that list

Comment: We did not find any results for usb site:http://spsdev1/spchal/team1/Lists/Matts%20Q%20A/FAQS.aspx.

1.Should the list not contain spaces? 2. The term usb is 100% in the list, so why does it not return any titles?

Comment: Try `usb site:http://spsdev1/spchal/team1/Lists/Matts%20Q%20A/FAQS.aspx`

Comment: no go on that, do i need to do anything special with my list?
Under the search box web part properties i added that to the field, Additional query terms, the site:http:// ...and still no go

Comment: The list should be searchable so you can find the usb entries in normal search. The url should not include the view so it should be `usb site:http://spsdev1/spchal/team1/Lists/Matts%20Q%20A`

Comment: Right so I have site:http://spsdev1/spchal/team1/Lists/Matts%20Q%20A appended to query and the list i am using is searchable, do any additional services need to be installed on the server?
it still doesn't work, it has to be the way i am trying to search the list.

Comment: thats http://spsdev...